# Angular2 creating different versions of directives

Tags: angular

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSidebarMinimizer]'
})
export class SidebarMinimizeDirective {
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  toggleOpen($event: any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('sidebar-minimized');
  }
}
```

The above directive toggles a sidebar and minimizes it or shows it.  Right now, the sidebar defaults on being open, but what if I want the sidebar to be closed on some pages, do I have to create another directive that looks exactly like this one and include my code to have the sidebar default close?

My component.html

```
<button class="sidebar-minimizer" type="button" appSidebarMinimizer></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Input to alter the logic on demand. You can find more about that here: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding

Comment: Can you give me an example code wise on how this would work, having trouble putting it together